# Equivalent of dotnet build --version-suffix when using MSBuild.exe

Tags: .net, msbuild, dotnet-sdk

With the `dotnet build` tool from the .NET SDK, you can pass `--version-suffix`, for example to make prerelease packages with suffixes such as `rc1`, etc.

I am having to use `MSBuild.exe` directly in order to work around a bug with targetting `net35` and want to know what the equivalent command line argument is for this.

Answer (score 5):

Add the `VersionSuffix` property to your `msbuild` arguments:

> msbuild /p:VersionSuffix=rc2 ...

Comment: This net35 issue is painful. Just go to 'this step'. Thanks for this!